# sequelise querying by createdAt today

Tags: sequelize.js

I have tried with

```
MyModal.findAll({
    where:{ 
      userId: userId,
      createdAt:new Date()
    }
});
```

But the above returns empty data set always

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this

```
MyModal.findAll({
    where:{ 
       $and: [
           { userId: userId },
           sequelize.where(
              sequelize.fn('DATE', sequelize.col('created_at')),
              sequelize.literal('CURRENT_DATE')
           )
       ]
    }
});
```

that will generate query

`DATE(created_at) = CURRENT_DATE`